# How change the class name on click event

Tags: jquery

i want to change the class name as active on click event... I want to remove the class name active from first li tag and to append the class name active as in 'Menu1' for both li tag and vice versa also...how to do this stuff with JQuery

```
<ul>
<li class="active">menu</li>
<li class="">
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="">menu1</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="">menu2</li>
```

to something like this

```
<ul>
<li class="">menu</li>
<li class="active">
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="active">menu1</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="">menu2</li>
```

Comment: i tried but i cannot able to give ACTIVE at both the place in LI class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up on clicking any `<li>` element, you can remove class `active` from all list items then add that `active` class only to the current clicked list item as well as the closest `li` parent by using `.closest()`:

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
    $('ul li').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active').closest('li').addClass('active')
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jQ64p/)**

---

Edit: Ignore above answer, you can use `.find()` instead to add active class to the child `li` inside submenu:

```
$('li').click(function () {
    $('li').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active').find('li').addClass('active');
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jQ64p/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').click(function()
{
$(this).toggleClass('active');
return false;

});
```

Plese refer this link for more

[Toggle class](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) or  [addclass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
$('li.active').toggleClass('active').next('li').toggleClass('active').find('li').toggleClass('active');
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2yy2a/)

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing would be to remove all active classes in the dom, using `$("li").removeClass("active")`and then the class active to the selected item, so it would something like:

```
$("li").on("click", function(){
   $("li").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```